# CTRL+ENTER on a file in Windows 7 Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, autohotkey

The .py files are associated to SublimeText on my Windows 7. Thus, when hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when the cursor/selection is on a .py file in the Explorer, SublimeText opens it. I want to keep this.

How to make that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> (or another short shortcut like <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, but no contextual menu) can start the .py file with `C:\Python27\python.exe <filename.py>`?

Note: if not possible with Explorer, I'm open to use AutoHotKey.

Comment: Sounds like [context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a general solution to the **"Can I have an action when doing <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> keyboard shortcut on a file in Explorer?"** problem, with AutoHotkey + Python.

1. Open `Regedit` and create a key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Second action x`. Set the default string in it as `Second action &x` (this little ampersand `&`  will make it available from contextual menu with key <kbd>X</kbd>).
2. Create another key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Second action x\command` and put this in it: `"C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "D:\secondaction\secondactionhandler.py" "%1"`
3. Create a Python script that will handle the action to do when doing WIN+ENTER, for example in `D:\secondaction\secondactionhandler.py`:

   ```
   import sys, os, subprocess
   fname = sys.argv[1]
   ext = os.path.splitext(fname)[-1].lower()
       if ext == '.py':
           subprocess.Popen(["C:\Python27\python.exe", fname])
       elif ext == '.wav':
           pass      # do your own things here for each extension
       else:
           subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe", fname])
   ```
4. Now, as we don't want to do Right click (contextual menu) + hit <kbd>X</kbd>, let's use this AutoHotkey script to associate it to <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

   ```
   #ENTER::
   Send {AppsKey}
   Send X
   Return
   ```

Now you can customize all your Explorer default actions for <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> :)
Here for example, I have put the default action to be Sublime Text except for .py files and .wav files.